# MatLab Bottleneck

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am working with big arrays (~6x40million) and my code is showing great bottlenecks. I am experienced programming in MatLab, but don't know much about the inner processes (like memory and such...).

My code looks as follows(Just the essentials, of course all variables are initialized, specially the arrays in loops, I just don't want to bomb you all with code ):

First I read the file,

```
 disp('Point cloud import and subsampling')
    tic
    fid=fopen(strcat(Name,'.dat'));
    C=textscan(fid, '%d%d%f%f%f%d'); %<= Big!
    fclose(fid);
```

then create arrays out of the contents,

```
    y=C{1}(1:Subsampling:end)/Subsampling;
    x=C{2}(1:Subsampling:end)/Subsampling;
    %... and so on for the other rows    

    clear C %No one wants 400+ millon doubles just lying around.
```

And clear the cell array (**1**), and create some images and arrays with the new values

```
for i=1:length(x)

    PCImage(y(i)+SubSize(1)-maxy+1,x(i)+1-minx)=Reflectanse(i);     
    PixelCoordinates(y(i)+SubSize(1)-maxy+1,x(i)+1-minx,:)=Coordinates(i,:);

end
toc
```

Everything runs more or less smoothly until here, but then I manipulate some arrays

```
disp('Overlap alignment')
   tic

    PCImage=PCImage(:,[1:maxx/2-Overlap,maxx/2:end-Overlap]); %-30 overlap?
    PixelCoordinates=PixelCoordinates(:,[1:maxx/2-Overlap,maxx/2:end-Overlap],:);
    Sphere=Sphere(:,[1:maxx/2-Overlap,maxx/2:end-Overlap],:);

toc
```

and this is a big bottleneck, but it gets worst at the next step

```
disp('Planar view and point cloud matching')
   tic

   CompImage=zeros(max(SubSize(1),PCSize(1)),max(SubSize(2),PCSize(2)),3);

   CompImage(1:SubSize(1),1:SubSize(2),2)=Subimage; %ExportImage Cyan
   CompImage(1:SubSize(1),1:SubSize(2),3)=Subimage;
   CompImage(1:PCSize(1),1:PCSize(2),1)=PCImage; %PointCloudImage Red

  toc
```

Output

> Point cloud import and subsampling
>
> Elapsed time is 181.157182 seconds.
>
> Overlap alignment
>
> Elapsed time is 408.750932 seconds.
>
> Planar view and point cloud matching
>
> Elapsed time is 719.383807 seconds.

My questions are: will clearing unused objects like `C` in **1** have any effect? (it doesn't seem like that)

Am I overseeing any other important mechanisms or rules of thumb, or is the whole thing just too much and supposed to happen like this?

Comment: I have also experienced problems with subsref. I am not really sure of how it works though. However, if it is possible I think it would be faster to just add up the vectors directly like `CompImage = [Subimage,Subimage,PCImage]`. Even if I see that this currently would be a problem for you, using your current code.

Comment: Another thing, when using subsref, matlab need to allocate memory for a new vector to store that data exracted from the vector. This is costly if the size of the extracted elements is large. This would have been clear if the coding were done in some low level programming language, but it can easily be overlooked in matlab. Think for example if you do `c=a(10:100)`. You definitely must use the value here and not a pointer, since this is the way matlab work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `subsref` is used, matlab makes a copy of the sub referenced elements. This may be costly for large arrays. Often it will be faster to catenate vectors like

```
res = [a,b,c];
```

This is not possible with the current code as written above, but if the code could be modified to make this work, it may save some time.

**EDIT**
For multi-dimensional arrays you need to use `cat`

```
CompImage = cat(dim,Subimage,Subimage,PCImage);
```

where `dim` is 3 for this example.

Comment: Wasn't so easy to modify after all, you see, the arrays had to be concatenated in the 3rd dimension. But I did test how subsref does indeed take a lot of time with large arrays.

Comment: @McMa Sorry about that, you must use `cat` for the third dimension. See my edit

Comment: I tried it now and it makes a hughe difference in computation time, thanks!